# How to save multiple ImageViews as one Bitmap while maintaining position of each ImageView in Android?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I have three ImageViews that I need to be able to save as one single Bitmap. The following code works to save the three ImageViews as one Bitmap but it pushes each image to the top left corner thus destroying the look of the image to the user. Two of the ImageViews are filled with color, the other is an actual image. How can I save the ImageViews as one Bitmap while still maintaining their position in the layout?

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
    public void saveDrawer(){
        Bitmap mainBmp = backImage.getDrawingCache();
        Bitmap centerBmp = centerImage.getDrawingCache();
        Bitmap handleBmp = handleImage.getDrawingCache();

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mainBmp);
        canvas.drawBitmap(centerBmp, 1, 1, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(handleBmp, 1, 1, null);

        OutputStream fOut = null;
        try {
            File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + File.separator + "CustomDrawer" + File.separator);
            root.mkdirs();
            File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, "customdrawer.png");
            fOut = new FileOutputStream(sdImageMainDirectory);
            Log.d("Path", fOut.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error occured. Please try again later.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        try {
            mainBmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

The resulting image is supposed to look like this:

[image]

But instead looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Always start with looking at the [docs for the methods you're using!](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
canvas.drawBitmap(handleBmp, 1, 1, null);
```

that 1,1, can set the position

Comment: Although that works to position each image correctly on the canvas prior to saving, the values used don't translate the same on higher or lower resolution screens. Worked perfectly for my phone but position was way off on other phones. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to the context of this question, what I think you should do is, arrange all your ImageView in single parent layout for example LinearLayout or FrameLayout or may be RelativeLayout. And then get your drawing cache from one of these parent and save that bitmap to SD.

Note : enable and disable the drawing cache on the layout accordingly. This is what i had done.

```
relativeLayoutBackground.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
relativeLayoutBackground.buildDrawingCache(true);
Bitmap bitmap = relativeLayoutBackground.getDrawingCache();
```

Comment: oh... also you must build the drawing cache before getting ...  setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            buildDrawingCache(true); and then .getDrawingCache()...have you tried that ?