# how i can print screen a single part of my layout?

Tags: android

thank you in advance for your attention.

I need a print screen in only one part of my layout and not in it all.
For example, below I have 2 `cardViews`, one of them is just a random `cardview`, I would like to save only one image of the second `cardView`, which contains the text "I want to print screen just this `CardView`", only it, and not all the rest Objects in the layout.

[image Example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BSc8.jpg)

I have no idea how to do this.
Has anyone ever faced the same difficulty or know how I can do it? thank you again.

Comment: use drawing caches - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39466552/how-to-save-multiple-imageviews-as-one-bitmap-while-maintaining-position-of-each/39467067#39467067

Comment: Hi! i will try its! if i can resolve my problem i will close this post. Thanks for you help!

Comment: @JoãoArmando see my answer you can pass any view inside this function not only cardview but many more like relativeLayout, LinearLayout, FrameLayout etc.You can also capture the full screen Screenshot using given the id to parent layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
CardView card = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.card);
```

Now just pass the card to captureScreenShot(). It returns the bitmap and save that bitmap saveImage().

You can pass any view Like RelativeLayout, LinearLayout etc any view can pass to captureScreenShot().

```
// Function which capture Screenshot
public Bitmap captureScreenShot(View view) {
    /*
     * Creating a Bitmap of view with ARGB_4444.
     * */
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Drawable backgroundDrawable = view.getBackground();

    if (backgroundDrawable != null) {
        backgroundDrawable.draw(canvas);
    } else {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.parseColor("#80000000"));
    }
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}

// Function which Save image.
private void saveImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
    File file = // Your Storage directory name + your filename
    if (file == null) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Finally call this function like this.

```
saveImage(captureScreenShot(card));
```

Comment: Hi @AndyDeveloper, This worked perfectly for me, and it was exactly what I needed. Many thanks for your great help!

Answer (score 1):

get id of your card view then:

```
CardView view = (CardView )findViewById(R.id.card_view);

view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

view.buildDrawingCache();

Bitmap bm = view.getDrawingCache();
```